# Find rows with Empty columns without mentioning column name

Tags: mysql

I want to find the rows from my db tables which has empty columns.
Suppose my table has 10 columns and 100 rows, any of the 10 columns could be NULL/EMPTY.

So I can't use WHERE command

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE REVENUE IS NULL OR ID IS NULL OR INCOME IS NULL   ....(this goes on till 10 columns)
```

How can I write this query to select rows which has got empty/null values (in any column).

Comment: you can use the `where` command

Comment: Can you elaborate, Pala. 
With where command if you have multiple (may be 10 or 15) columns & dunno which column has null value .. you got to mention all the columns with where command.

eg: SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE c1 IS NULL OR  C2 IS NULL OR
C3 IS NULL OR C4 IS NULL OR ........ C15 IS NULL.
This process is tedious.
There should be a better solution to this. Sorry, I don't know the answer. I am stuck with something similar.

Comment: You can construct a prepared statement from the information_schema.columns table, and then execute that prepared statement. It's somewhat messy tho - probably easier to build the query at the application layer

Comment: Hey Very New Newbie,Are you using this query in any programming language such as java or php or anything else to execute this query.Or just accomplish the task using mysql command line.Please be specific.So i can help out with the programming language.

Comment: These kinds of problems can be indicative of poor design although in your case it's impossible to say without more information

Answer (score 1):

The table `information_schema.columns` contains column info for every table in every database in the system. We can extract the column names for your table from this, and use it to build a prepared statement, which we can execute to find your values.

Assuming your database is called `foo` and your table is called `test`, we can do this:

```
select concat("SELECT * FROM test WHERE ", group_concat(concat(column_name, " IS NULL ") SEPARATOR "OR "))
  into @sql
  from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'test'
      and table_schema = 'foo';
```

This will generate, and store in `@sql`, a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
    WHERE id IS NULL 
      OR col1 IS NULL 
      OR col2 IS NULL 
      OR col3 IS NULL 
      OR col4 IS NULL 
      OR col5 IS NULL
```

We then prepare our statement like this:

```
prepare stmt from @sql
```

And then we execute it to get your values

```
execute stmt
```

And finally, we deallocate the statement.

```
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

This would be an example output from that sequence:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|  2 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|  3 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|  4 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 | NULL |
|  5 | NULL |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|  6 |    1 | NULL |    3 |    4 |    5 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select concat("SELECT * FROM test WHERE ", group_concat(concat(column_name, " IS NULL ") SEPARATOR "OR "))
    ->   into @sql
    ->   from information_schema.columns
    ->     where table_name = 'test'
    ->       and table_schema = 'foo';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
|  4 |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 | NULL |
|  5 | NULL |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |
|  6 |    1 | NULL |    3 |    4 |    5 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> deallocate prepare stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Good one Pala ! 

Thank you.

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu No problem - if this is a suitable answer for you, could you please mark it as accepted

Comment: That wasn't my question or I would have.

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu haha. woops. not used to being commented on by others :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do but you need to use PL/SQL. Is it okay with you???

Comment: Yes, should be fine. 
Good if we can solve it through procedures. 

Can you please help me with that ?


Thanks a tonn!

Comment: Yes i have found one similar solution,Below is the link for the same:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737725/how-to-get-rows-whose-columns-values-are-not-null